# Redirecting to a new page without frames

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frames

I have a framed site (i cannot change this), when i redirect out of my site using

```
 window.location
```

to one of our other sites it inserts the page into the main frame such that the other frames still exist.

I do not want this, the page must completely change to the different website. How can i do this using.

```
javascript/php/jquery
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `window.top.location` to change the top frame's (main page's) location.

Answer (score 3):

```
window.top.location = "newpage.html";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you exactly, but maybe this is what you looking for

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30; URL=http://yoursite.com">
```